# Text Substitution on a Mac

Tags: macos

My question is regarding the text substitution feature of my MacBook Air running El Capitan. Are the substitutions stored in an editable file somewhere on my system? If so, where? If not, is there anyway to bulk load substitutions instead of adding them one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text substitutions are stored in `~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist` as an array under the `NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems` key.

See [How can I export text substitutions from Lion for import into Mountain Lion](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204006) and [How to export and import text substitutions in OS X](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204006) for some ideas on editing the file, though you could also edit it directly using XCode or any `plist` editor.

Comment: Thanks leeka. I'll check this out. It sounds like what I'm looking for.